# Background color messing up UI

Tags: java, android, debugging

So when I set the color of the background color of the app to pink I get this.

[Image of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV3fu.png)

This is my style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF00FF</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FF00FF</item>
</style>
```

And my android manifest:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.jotarstudios.autosettingsswitch.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: remove this **<item name="android:background">#FF00FF</item>**. if you want to set the background color of window background, use **<item name="android:windowBackground">#FF00FF</item>**

Comment: Thanks man it worked! I really appreciate it, I couldn't figure it out. @Sanny

Comment: would you like to tick it as answer if it helps you ? :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are setting background of window, you would need to

Replace this

```
<item name="android:background">#FF00FF</item>
```

with this

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">#FF00FF</item>
```